# Usar una interfaz genérica y una implementación concreta

Tags: java, sql, poo, jdbc

tengo esta duda no se por que en un ejercicio tengo esta implementacion

```
 Repositorio<Producto> repositorio = new ProductoRepositorioImpl();
```

es una interface repositorio generico

```
public interface Repositorio <T>{
List <T> listar() throws SQLException;
T porId();
void guardar();
void eliminar();}
```

una clase concreta que va a implementar Repositorio

```
public class ProductoRepositorioImpl implements Repositorio<Producto> {

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ConexionBaseDatos.getConnection();
}
@Override
public List<Producto> listar() throws SQLException {
    List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
    try(Statement stmt = getConnection().createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultado = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM productos");
        while (resultado.next()){
            Producto p = new Producto();
            p.setNombre(resultado.getString("nombre"));
            p.setId(resultado.getLong("id"));
            p.setPrecio(resultado.getInt("precio"));
            p.setFechaRegistro(resultado.getDate("fecha_registro"));
            productos.add(p);
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return productos;
}

@Override
public Producto porId() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void guardar() {

}

@Override
public void eliminar() {

}}
```

y la clase main

```
public class EjemploJdbc {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = ConexionBaseDatos.getConnection();) {
        Repositorio<Producto> repositorio = new ProductoRepositorioImpl();

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

quiero suponer que es por que no puedo crear el objeto producto ya que no tiene los metodos del crud que quiero usar, esos metodos estan en ProductoRepositorio, entonces quiero creer que usamos Repositorio  para decirle que vamos a usar productos y usar sus atributos e instanciar la clase concreta ProductosRepositorio para usar sus metodos del crud pero no se si estoy en lo correcto

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? No veo ni un signo de interrogación.

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso tiene sentido declararlo como una interfaz si luego puede haber varias implementaciones distintas. Por ejemplo, puedes tener un `Repositorio<T>` y luego implementaciones como `MySQLRepositorio<T>` o `MongoRepositorio<T>`, que implementan la interfaz de forma genérica:

```java
public class MySQLRepositorio<T> implements Repositorio<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Ahora bien, tener una única implementación y para una entidad concreta (`ProductoRepositorioImpl` para `Producto`) no tiene mucha aplicación práctica.  En el mundo real se usaría inyección de dependencias, siendo este sistema el que te proporciona el objeto ya creado que implemente esa interfaz. Pides un objeto de `Repositorio<Producto>`, es decir, que implemente esta interfaz, y el sistema (o el lugar desde donde llames) provee una implementación en función de ciertas cosas. Por ejemplo, imaginemos que de algún modo sabemos si se quiere usar MySQL o MongoDB:

```java
public class EjemploJdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        bool mysql = true;
        if (mysql) {
            listarProductos(new MysqlRepositorio<Producto>());
        } else {
            listarProductos(new MongoRepositorio<Producto>());
        }
    }

    public static void listarProductos(Repositorio<Producto> repositorio) {
        // Aquí no sabe si es MysqlRepositorio o si es MongoRepositorio
        System.out.println(
            repositorio.listar()
        );
    }
}
```

En el `listarProductos` da igual que entre una implementación u otra, porque ambas tienen que cumplir la intefaz. Da igual cual de las dos recibas, porque en ambos casos `listar()` te va a devolver una `List<Producto>`.